# jQuery fullcalendar - how to reduce the size of the calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using jQuery fullcalendar in my application. I want to display the calendar only on the right side of my screen but not sure how to reduce the size of the calendar. Right now it is displaying in the full screen

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372328/tiny-version-of-fullcalendar/5372990#5372990

Answer (score 17):

Just stick it in a div with a specified width as per home page for [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

```
<div id='container'>
...
<div id='calendar'></div>
...
</div>
```

with css

```
#container {
    width: 810px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a property in JSON field which we passing in the fullCalender method.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    height: 650
})
```

Referenced Url:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/height/

Answer (score 1):

reduce the aspect ratio of the full calendar

Answer (score 1):

In My application side bar, I Simply used like this.

Your `Html`

`<div id='calendar'></div>`

You can write `css` like this.

```
#calendar
{
    width: 400px;
}
```

alter width in pixel range, how much you need.
I'm also using like this. It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div id='calendar' style="width:95%"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question! This answer is very short though and doesn't provide much context. Please explain some of the reasoning behind it, and it will become much more useful for the asker and future readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a div container to control width and height.

you can control only the heigh of the calendar by adding

```
> $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>     height: 650 
> });
```