# Tiny version of fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am hoping someone can tell me how to get a very small version of FullCalendar (or something similar) that will do a widget size calendar without titles, just colored blocks for dates with events that can be clicked on. I am using fullcalendar in a wordpress site which is great, but all the google calendar widgets out there really suck!

Answer (score 65):

You can make a fully functional tiny version by adding a bit of CSS. I had to add a "eventMouseover" callback to add the event name to the title attribute, so you can see it's name in the tooltip.

Here is a screen shot of the mini-sized calendar (200 x 225) and a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/G6K6Y/1739/).

[image]

The CSS

```
#calendar {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.fc-header-title h2 {
    font-size: .9em;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
.fc-view-month .fc-event, .fc-view-agendaWeek .fc-event {
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 2px;
}
.fc-view-agendaWeek .fc-event-vert {
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 2px !important;
}
.fc-agenda-axis {
    width: 20px !important;
    font-size: .7em;
}

.fc-button-content {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,

        // add event name to title attribute on mouseover
        eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            if (view.name !== 'agendaDay') {
                $(jsEvent.target).attr('title', event.title);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

---

**Updated**: Made week view horizontal events smaller and made all events 2px wide or high to make it easier to hover over them.

---

**Update v2.4+** Instead of updating the above answer, I'll just post the modified code I used to make FullCalendar v2.4 tiny ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/G6K6Y/1482/))

CSS

```
#calendar {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.fc-toolbar {
    font-size: .9em;
}
.fc-toolbar h2 {
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
/* click +2 more for popup */
.fc-more-cell a {
    display: block;
    width: 85%;
    margin: 1px auto 0 auto;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: grey;
    color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 4px;
}
.fc-more-popover {
    width: 100px;
}
.fc-view-month .fc-event, .fc-view-agendaWeek .fc-event, .fc-content {
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 2px;
}
.fc-view-agendaWeek .fc-event-vert {
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 2px !important;
}
.fc-agenda-axis {
    width: 20px !important;
    font-size: .7em;
}

.fc-button-content {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

        eventAfterRender: function () {
            // add titles to "+# more links"
            $('.fc-more-cell a').each(function () {
                this.title = this.textContent;
            });
        },

        // add event name to title attribute on mouseover
        eventMouseover: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
            if (view.name !== 'agendaDay') {
                $(jsEvent.target).attr('title', event.title);
            }
        },

        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true // allow "more" link when too many events

    });

});
```

Comment: Hi this is great. Thank you very much. But it doesn't seem to work completely on FullCalenar 2.0.
The cells are rendered to large (vertically). Have you ayn idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hi @Dave! I've updated my answer - [new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/G6K6Y/1482/) - the changes add a title and a grey background to the "+2 more" link, and reduce the pop up size.

Comment: This is slick, thanks for sharing