# Fullcalendar : how to minimize at maximum the UI?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Is that possible to minimize the UI at maximum in order to **look like jQuery UI datepicker** (i mean the same dimensions) ?
I love the functionalities of Fullcalendar but I need to display it in a small box.

1) how to minimize at maximum the UI i only need a minimal UI like jquery UI datepicker ?

2) How, instead of displaying the event in the case where the day is displayed, to just display the number of the day and apply a custom style on it to make it clickable ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a view other than what fullcalendar provides, you can work on building your own [View](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/).  As of 1.5 this option [should be available](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=380) (the issue is marked closed as of March), but documentation does not yet appear on the site.  When you create a custom view you will be able to style it however you like.

To set the calendar to a certain height, you can pass an option at start-up:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 200
});
```

or set it dynamically:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', 200);
```

Comment: Thanks i'll give it a try to minimize it finding options browing github

Comment: Sadly setting the height like that doesn't work, but you can just style the calendar using css! Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372328/tiny-version-of-fullcalendar/5372990#5372990).